# Login invalid giving specified cast is invalid

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling

I have a login form and modified some code from another source to make it work for my situation.  I am getting the error when the login is not valid because the number is empty or 'infinite'.

```
public int Validate_Login(String Username, String Password)
{

    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"User id=judgment_day;Password=Kit$hen;Server=216.40.232.82, 2153;Database=new_judgment-system");
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CityCollectionCSharp.Properties.Settings.newCityCollectionConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmdselect = new SqlCommand();
    cmdselect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdselect.CommandText = "[dbo].[prcLoginv]";
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Username;
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@UPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Password;
    cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmdselect.Connection = con;
    int Results = 0;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Results = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmdselect.Dispose();

        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return Results;
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
Results = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
```

How would I go about error handling that so when it is not a valid integer that it will trigger the invalid login which the code is here:

```
protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Results = 0;


    if (txtUsername.Text != null && txtPassword.Text != null)
    {
        Results = Validate_Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        if (Results > 0)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Login is Good";

            GlobalVariables.Globals.SetGlobalInt(Results);
            lblMessage.Text = "'" + GlobalVariables.Globals.GlobalInt + "'";
            this.Hide();
            frmSwitch frm = new frmSwitch();
            frm.Show();   
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Login";
            lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "Please make sure that the username and the password is Correct";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have majority of the code in place.  I think you are not understanding how exceptions are handled - Read up on [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and you should be able to follow the example below.

As you do not specify the exact `Exception` being raised, I have added a general Excepion handler.

```
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // Check for null values
        if (cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
           Results = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    catch (Exception generalEx)
    {
        // Do something with the error - Just displaying for now
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmdselect.Dispose();

        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

The code is just for illustration, edit as required.

Comment: Thanks Kami.  I think I was being lazy and forgot the if statement.  This was originally set up to be 0 or 1 but I needed to pass the actual to other parts of my software and missed a major part.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
    object o = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
    if (o == DBNull.Value)
        return 0;
    return (int)o;
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
}
finally
....
```

and the `finally` block takes care of the resources.